# How to extract text ending with new line marker in r using regex

Tags: r, extract

### Question

I have a character vecter `a` that mix letter and Chinese character. I want to extract the `5 Classes`. Like the example below.

I don't know how to do it in R.

I have tried `ex_between()` from `qdapRegex`package but failed.

### Reproducible code

```
a = "Class1：AAA_123_视物。\nClass2：BBB_456，行手术。\nClass3：CCC_789\nClass4：DDD_111\nEEE_222\nFFF_333\nClass5：GGG_444_右：光感？  "

# I used ex_between() from qdapRegex package to extract Class1 to Class5 but failed.
Class1 = ex_between(a, 'Class1：', '\n')
Class2 = ex_between(a, 'Class2：', '\n')
Class3 = ex_between(a, 'Class3：', '\n')
Class4 = ex_between(a, 'Class4：', '\n')
Class5 = ex_between(a, 'Class1：', ' ')
```

### Expected output

```
Class1 = "AAA_123_视物。"
Class2 = "BBB_456，行手术。"
Class3 = "CCC_789"
Class4 = "DDD_111,EEE_222,FFF_333" # Note that \n has been replaced with comma(,)
Class5 = "GGG_444_右：光感？  "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `ex_between()` function has a limited control over regex, especially for the
case of `Class4` which should not terminate the match at the first encountered
newline character, I'd use `str_extract()` function instead.
Would you please try:

```
library(stringr)

a = "Class1：AAA_123_视物。\nClass2：BBB_456，行手术。\nClass3：CCC_789\nClass4：DDD_111\nEEE_222\nFFF_333\nClass5：GGG_444_右：光感？  "

Class1 = str_extract(a, regex("(?<=Class1：).*?(?=\nClass)", dotall=TRUE))
Class2 = str_extract(a, regex("(?<=Class2：).*?(?=\nClass)", dotall=TRUE))
Class3 = str_extract(a, regex("(?<=Class3：).*?(?=\nClass)", dotall=TRUE))
Class4 = str_extract(a, regex("(?<=Class4：).*?(?=\nClass)", dotall=TRUE))
Class5 = str_extract(a, regex("(?<=Class5：).*"))
```

Output:

```
Class1 = "AAA_123_视物。"
Class2 = "BBB_456，行手术。"
Class3 = "CCC_789"
Class4 = "DDD_111\nEEE_222\nFFF_333"
Class5 = "GGG_444_右：光感？  "
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=Class1：)` is a lookbehind assertion and the matched portion is
  not included in the result.
- `.*?` is the shortest match between the lookbehind (above)
  and the lookahead (below).
- `(?=\nClass)` is a lookahead which matches the string "Class" preceded
  by a newline.
- The `dotall=TRUE` option makes a dot match a newline character.